# swap two pointers to exchange arrays

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

I have the following code which I want to make it so that board now has the value of new_board and vice versa. Since they are both pointers I thought I could just swap the addresses they point to. When I print in print2() the addresses are appropriately swapped. However, when I print in print1() the addresses have somehow swapped back, which doesn't make any sense to me. Further if I print out the values in the board at print2() they are also correct.

```
main(){
  char *new_board = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * rows * cols );
  char *board = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * rows * cols );
  update_board2(board, new_board, rows, cols);
  print1();
}

void update_board2(char *board, char *new_board, int rows, int cols){
  //do a bunch of stuff
  char *temp = board;
  board = new_board;
  new_board = temp;
  print2();
}
```

Comment: Pointers (like all other objects) are passed _by value_ in C. `update_board2` is operating of copies of the arguments passed. Also `new_board` and `board` are not declared as pointers. What compile errors and warnings are you getting?

Comment: Sorry in my code they are, I miscopied.

Comment: Also, [don't cast the return value of malloc() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and avoid `sizeof (char)` since it's just a very verbose 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to change the values of the pointers themselves, then the function `update_board2` has to accept double pointers. Otherwise the pointers get copied within the function and you are swapping only these temporary copies rather than the real pointers the caller has passed:

```
void update_board2(char **board, char **new_board){
  char *temp = *board;
  *board = *new_board;
  *new_board = temp;
  print2();
}
```

Comment: who knew. That was pretty confusing glad I learned a new source of confounding bugs today. I guess the fact that the values switched as soon as the function returned should have been a give away that it was copied by value not reference.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make the following change:

```
update_board2(&board, &new_board, rows, cols);

void update_board2(char **board, char **new_board, int rows, int cols){
  //do a bunch of stuff
  char *temp = *board;
  *board = *new_board;
  *new_board = temp;
  print2();
}
```

In this case pointers will be swapped correctly.

Comment: And you can remove rows and cols parameters, as they are not used in the function.

Comment: @Patryk They are supposed to be used in `//do a bunch of stuff` as I understand.

Answer (score 3):

your main needs to be fixed too

i.e.

```
char * new_board = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * rows * cols );
char * board = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * rows * cols );
```

malloc returns a pointer, not a character.