# c - swapping strings pass by value rather than reference?

Tags: c

I made a code to swap two strings:

```
void swap (char *a, char *b)
{
    char *t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

int main()
{
    char * strings[2];
    strings [0] = "luck!";
    strings [1] = "good ";
    swap (strings[0], strings[1]);
    printf( "%s %s\n",strings[0], strings[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

And it fails. What i have trouble understanding is when i call `swap()` i pass two pointers. Both pointers point to the first character of their assigned arrays. I then created a temporary pointer inside the function and perform basic switch. What is flawed here? I really want to understand why this approach is wrong?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `strcpy`.

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi the point is to learn c

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246615/swap-two-pointers-to-exchange-arrays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are switching the parameters of the function, which are local to the function scope. When your function is executed, the parameters (a, of type char*, and b, of type char*) are passed by value, put on the stack, and the function is executed. The parameters are modified and then popped of the stack without effect.

To make a difference, you need to pass *references* to the parameters:

```
void swap (char **a, char **b)
{
    char *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

and then call with:

```
swap (&strings[0], &strings[1]);
```

You now pass pointers to individual array elements in `strings`, which is in main's stack segment and thereby persists past the context of `swap`.

Comment: But please note that it doesn't make much sense in a real world application to swap two pointers like this.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a copy to the pointers to the function and thus you exchange the copies. In `C` you will have to pass a pointer to the pointers to actually swap them.

Comment: So the pointers themselves are copied? I thought that passing an array  happens by reference rather than by value

Comment: Yes but you are not passing an array, you are passing one of array's elements. Keep in mind your array stores pointers so in fact a char pointer is an element instead of pointer the the whole array.

Comment: @Tom: pointers themselves are always passed by value. It's not entirely correct to claim that "arrays are passed by reference", however. Arrays decay to pointers in most contexts, so you are really passing a pointer by value instead of the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap values through pointers, you need to use assigments of the form

```
*a = *b;
```

If you would do that in your code, it would swap the first *characters* of the strings. To swap the pointers, you need to have paraemters of type `char**`, and pass `&strings[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you example, about what other answers suggesting ...

Update your `swap` function to

```
void swap (char **a, char **b)
{
    char *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

And then call it in main as

```
swap(&strings[0], &strings[1]);
```

However, you may want to update assignment of strings as string like "luck!" is constant and you cannot update its individual characters.

```
strings [0] = strdup("luck!");
strings [1] = strdup("good ");
```